# Mapping dynamic response to Java Object in RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, exception, resttemplate

I've used RestTemplate to consume remote REST API and I'm getting two different responses for the same request depend on data availability.

eg:- Valid Response

`User {
  username,
  password
}`

Error Response when user not found in records.

`Error {
  errorCode,
  errorMessage
}`

And this User response has mapped using `restTemplate.getForEntity("url", User.class)`.

Additionally handled RestTemplate Errors using **ResponseErrorHandler**,

Is there any way to capture both **User** response and **Error** Response using resttemplate in same time?

Answer (score 1):

I usually include both/all option and ignore null values, below example

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class ResponseVO {
    private User user;

    private Error error;
}
```

If all data in same level, you can add all members in same class